# Function with array called multiple times inside other function

Tags: php, arrays, function

I have one function called several times inside other function. Something like that:

```
function function_one()
{

global $get, $count;

function_two ();
$ok1 = $get[0]; 

function_two ();
$ok2 = $get[1]; 

function_two ();
$ok3 = $get[2]; 

}
```

In the “function_two()”, I have the variable “$get” who is set as an array, and I have a counter, something like that:

```
function function_two()
{

    global $get, $count;

    // something here

    $get = array();

    if (isset($count))
    {
        $count = $count;
    } else {
        $count = 0;
    }

    $get[$count] = $some_value;

    $count ++;

}
```

The problem: only the “$ok3” are full, the others came empty. Please help me!

Comment: What does function_two do, exactly? Don't use global inside functions. If you want to pass values cross functions, use parameters.

Comment: Please don't use global! Pass your variables as parameter. Also give us a [mcve]

Comment: is the second function you defined  is `function_two`? is that a typo that you wrote both function as `function_one`?

Comment: Is the TAB key broken on your computer? Please indent your code.

Comment: Are you really doing the assignments immediately after you call the function? If you call the function twice and then try to access multiple elements in `$get`, it won't work, because `function_two` empties the variable each time you call it when it does `$get = array();`.

Comment: @Barmar A broken tab key would be no excuse. There is still a space button and an auto-indent button in the IDE :)

Comment: That code is **complete nonsense** take a deep breath and give us a **syntactically plausable** example

Answer (score -1):

I'm assuming that the 2nd function is function two (You put function one)  the issue is the

```
$get=array();
```

This resets the get array to empty (all of it)
I would delete the line and move the `$get=array();` to your main function before all of this is called.  Or you can move it into the top of function one (the real function one)

Answer (score -1):

It appears your function_one() in the second comment is actually function_two(). Your problem is here:

```
 $get = array();
```

You format the **$get** variable as an empty array every time you call the function. Anyhow, **don't use globals**. Instead create a class with variables and use parameters.

```
class Count {

    public $get = array();

    function_two($count) {
       $this->get[$count] = $some_value;
       $count++;
       return $count;
    }

    function get() {
        return $this->get;
    }
}
```

Comment: Rcls, how I could use classes to make this script more elegant?

Comment: It worked! Thank you guys! I use Barmar and Forbs tips. Let me explain: these scrips are part of a universal script that creates thumbnails of an image sent by the user. Each "$get[x]" is the name of the new image (for example, could be width, height, path, size). This data is then recorded in the database. By universal I mean it can be used by any content of my site with a few lines of code.